# Обновление программы из .deb пакета

Tags: linux, ubuntu, deb, dpkg, apt

Я упаковал свою программу в deb пакет и при попытке обновить ее до более свежей версии с помощью apt install ./package.deb удаляются все предыдущие файлы и папки. Как мне сделать, чтобы новый deb пакет обновлял файлы, а не удалял их?

Все файлы распаковываются в /opt/mypackage/

Прикладываю control файл для наглядности:

```
Package: mypackage
Version: 2.0.0.98
Maintainer: security equipment manufacturer
Description: access control software
Homepage: https://example.org
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libvdpau-dev, libva-dev
Conflicts: mypackage
Replaces: mypackage
```

Answer (score 0):

Дуралеем оказался я сам. Как выяснилось, при обновлении пакета запускался скрипт postrm в котором вызывалось удаление каталога /opt/mypackage/

Comment: храни данные и программы отдельно друг от друга.